# How to create list of 50 different itext colors

Tags: itext, color-scheme

I'm creating pdf tables in java. Each cell has itext, portions of which I need to set the font colors depending on a substring in the cell. I know how to do everything except create a set of about 50 colors different enough from one another that all cells with a particular substring are easily spotted by the user.

Is there an a collection of colors I can use, a clever way of generating such a list?

TIA

Ed S

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look inside the [`WebColors`](https://github.com/itext/itextpdf/blob/master/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/text/html/WebColors.java) class. This class extends a `HashMap<String, int[]>` as well as a `public static` constant that is created like this:

```
public static final WebColors NAMES = new WebColors();
static {
    NAMES.put("aliceblue", new int[] { 0xf0, 0xf8, 0xff, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("antiquewhite", new int[] { 0xfa, 0xeb, 0xd7, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("aqua", new int[] { 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("aquamarine", new int[] { 0x7f, 0xff, 0xd4, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("azure", new int[] { 0xf0, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("beige", new int[] { 0xf5, 0xf5, 0xdc, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("bisque", new int[] { 0xff, 0xe4, 0xc4, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("black", new int[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("blanchedalmond", new int[] { 0xff, 0xeb, 0xcd, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("blue", new int[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("blueviolet", new int[] { 0x8a, 0x2b, 0xe2, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("brown", new int[] { 0xa5, 0x2a, 0x2a, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("burlywood", new int[] { 0xde, 0xb8, 0x87, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("cadetblue", new int[] { 0x5f, 0x9e, 0xa0, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("chartreuse", new int[] { 0x7f, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("chocolate", new int[] { 0xd2, 0x69, 0x1e, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("coral", new int[] { 0xff, 0x7f, 0x50, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("cornflowerblue", new int[] { 0x64, 0x95, 0xed, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("cornsilk", new int[] { 0xff, 0xf8, 0xdc, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("crimson", new int[] { 0xdc, 0x14, 0x3c, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("cyan", new int[] { 0x00, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("darkblue", new int[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x8b, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("darkcyan", new int[] { 0x00, 0x8b, 0x8b, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("darkgoldenrod", new int[] { 0xb8, 0x86, 0x0b, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("darkgray", new int[] { 0xa9, 0xa9, 0xa9, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("darkgreen", new int[] { 0x00, 0x64, 0x00, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("darkkhaki", new int[] { 0xbd, 0xb7, 0x6b, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("darkmagenta", new int[] { 0x8b, 0x00, 0x8b, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("darkolivegreen", new int[] { 0x55, 0x6b, 0x2f, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("darkorange", new int[] { 0xff, 0x8c, 0x00, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("darkorchid", new int[] { 0x99, 0x32, 0xcc, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("darkred", new int[] { 0x8b, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("darksalmon", new int[] { 0xe9, 0x96, 0x7a, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("darkseagreen", new int[] { 0x8f, 0xbc, 0x8f, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("darkslateblue", new int[] { 0x48, 0x3d, 0x8b, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("darkslategray", new int[] { 0x2f, 0x4f, 0x4f, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("darkturquoise", new int[] { 0x00, 0xce, 0xd1, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("darkviolet", new int[] { 0x94, 0x00, 0xd3, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("deeppink", new int[] { 0xff, 0x14, 0x93, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("deepskyblue", new int[] { 0x00, 0xbf, 0xff, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("dimgray", new int[] { 0x69, 0x69, 0x69, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("dodgerblue", new int[] { 0x1e, 0x90, 0xff, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("firebrick", new int[] { 0xb2, 0x22, 0x22, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("floralwhite", new int[] { 0xff, 0xfa, 0xf0, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("forestgreen", new int[] { 0x22, 0x8b, 0x22, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("fuchsia", new int[] { 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("gainsboro", new int[] { 0xdc, 0xdc, 0xdc, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("ghostwhite", new int[] { 0xf8, 0xf8, 0xff, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("gold", new int[] { 0xff, 0xd7, 0x00, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("goldenrod", new int[] { 0xda, 0xa5, 0x20, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("gray", new int[] { 0x80, 0x80, 0x80, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("green", new int[] { 0x00, 0x80, 0x00, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("greenyellow", new int[] { 0xad, 0xff, 0x2f, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("honeydew", new int[] { 0xf0, 0xff, 0xf0, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("hotpink", new int[] { 0xff, 0x69, 0xb4, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("indianred", new int[] { 0xcd, 0x5c, 0x5c, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("indigo", new int[] { 0x4b, 0x00, 0x82, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("ivory", new int[] { 0xff, 0xff, 0xf0, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("khaki", new int[] { 0xf0, 0xe6, 0x8c, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("lavender", new int[] { 0xe6, 0xe6, 0xfa, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("lavenderblush", new int[] { 0xff, 0xf0, 0xf5, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("lawngreen", new int[] { 0x7c, 0xfc, 0x00, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("lemonchiffon", new int[] { 0xff, 0xfa, 0xcd, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("lightblue", new int[] { 0xad, 0xd8, 0xe6, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("lightcoral", new int[] { 0xf0, 0x80, 0x80, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("lightcyan", new int[] { 0xe0, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("lightgoldenrodyellow", new int[] { 0xfa, 0xfa, 0xd2, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("lightgreen", new int[] { 0x90, 0xee, 0x90, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("lightgrey", new int[] { 0xd3, 0xd3, 0xd3, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("lightpink", new int[] { 0xff, 0xb6, 0xc1, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("lightsalmon", new int[] { 0xff, 0xa0, 0x7a, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("lightseagreen", new int[] { 0x20, 0xb2, 0xaa, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("lightskyblue", new int[] { 0x87, 0xce, 0xfa, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("lightslategray", new int[] { 0x77, 0x88, 0x99, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("lightsteelblue", new int[] { 0xb0, 0xc4, 0xde, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("lightyellow", new int[] { 0xff, 0xff, 0xe0, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("lime", new int[] { 0x00, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("limegreen", new int[] { 0x32, 0xcd, 0x32, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("linen", new int[] { 0xfa, 0xf0, 0xe6, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("magenta", new int[] { 0xff, 0x00, 0xff, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("maroon", new int[] { 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("mediumaquamarine", new int[] { 0x66, 0xcd, 0xaa, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("mediumblue", new int[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0xcd, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("mediumorchid", new int[] { 0xba, 0x55, 0xd3, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("mediumpurple", new int[] { 0x93, 0x70, 0xdb, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("mediumseagreen", new int[] { 0x3c, 0xb3, 0x71, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("mediumslateblue", new int[] { 0x7b, 0x68, 0xee, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("mediumspringgreen", new int[] { 0x00, 0xfa, 0x9a, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("mediumturquoise", new int[] { 0x48, 0xd1, 0xcc, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("mediumvioletred", new int[] { 0xc7, 0x15, 0x85, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("midnightblue", new int[] { 0x19, 0x19, 0x70, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("mintcream", new int[] { 0xf5, 0xff, 0xfa, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("mistyrose", new int[] { 0xff, 0xe4, 0xe1, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("moccasin", new int[] { 0xff, 0xe4, 0xb5, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("navajowhite", new int[] { 0xff, 0xde, 0xad, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("navy", new int[] { 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("oldlace", new int[] { 0xfd, 0xf5, 0xe6, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("olive", new int[] { 0x80, 0x80, 0x00, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("olivedrab", new int[] { 0x6b, 0x8e, 0x23, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("orange", new int[] { 0xff, 0xa5, 0x00, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("orangered", new int[] { 0xff, 0x45, 0x00, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("orchid", new int[] { 0xda, 0x70, 0xd6, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("palegoldenrod", new int[] { 0xee, 0xe8, 0xaa, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("palegreen", new int[] { 0x98, 0xfb, 0x98, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("paleturquoise", new int[] { 0xaf, 0xee, 0xee, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("palevioletred", new int[] { 0xdb, 0x70, 0x93, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("papayawhip", new int[] { 0xff, 0xef, 0xd5, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("peachpuff", new int[] { 0xff, 0xda, 0xb9, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("peru", new int[] { 0xcd, 0x85, 0x3f, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("pink", new int[] { 0xff, 0xc0, 0xcb, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("plum", new int[] { 0xdd, 0xa0, 0xdd, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("powderblue", new int[] { 0xb0, 0xe0, 0xe6, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("purple", new int[] { 0x80, 0x00, 0x80, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("red", new int[] { 0xff, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("rosybrown", new int[] { 0xbc, 0x8f, 0x8f, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("royalblue", new int[] { 0x41, 0x69, 0xe1, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("saddlebrown", new int[] { 0x8b, 0x45, 0x13, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("salmon", new int[] { 0xfa, 0x80, 0x72, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("sandybrown", new int[] { 0xf4, 0xa4, 0x60, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("seagreen", new int[] { 0x2e, 0x8b, 0x57, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("seashell", new int[] { 0xff, 0xf5, 0xee, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("sienna", new int[] { 0xa0, 0x52, 0x2d, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("silver", new int[] { 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xc0, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("skyblue", new int[] { 0x87, 0xce, 0xeb, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("slateblue", new int[] { 0x6a, 0x5a, 0xcd, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("slategray", new int[] { 0x70, 0x80, 0x90, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("snow", new int[] { 0xff, 0xfa, 0xfa, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("springgreen", new int[] { 0x00, 0xff, 0x7f, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("steelblue", new int[] { 0x46, 0x82, 0xb4, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("tan", new int[] { 0xd2, 0xb4, 0x8c, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("teal", new int[] { 0x00, 0x80, 0x80, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("thistle", new int[] { 0xd8, 0xbf, 0xd8, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("tomato", new int[] { 0xff, 0x63, 0x47, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("transparent", new int[] { 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x00 });
    NAMES.put("turquoise", new int[] { 0x40, 0xe0, 0xd0, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("violet", new int[] { 0xee, 0x82, 0xee, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("wheat", new int[] { 0xf5, 0xde, 0xb3, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("white", new int[] { 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("whitesmoke", new int[] { 0xf5, 0xf5, 0xf5, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("yellow", new int[] { 0xff, 0xff, 0x00, 0xff });
    NAMES.put("yellowgreen", new int[] { 0x9a, 0xcd, 0x32, 0xff });
}
```

You can use any of these names like this:

```
BaseColor color = WebColors.getRGBColor(name);
```

where `name` is one of the values of the keys available in `NAMES`, such as `"aliceblue"`, `"antiquewhite"`, and so on. The colors were harvested from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors